# --headless flag no longer works after upgrade to chrome 76/chromedriver 76

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running python selenium tests using headless chrome. After updating to chrome Version `76.0.3809.87` and chromedriver version `ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68`, the `chromeOptions` that I use (see code sample below)... no longer work. i.e. the browser is launched (non headless) and the resolution settings are also not working

Anyone else seeing this after upgrading to chromedriver 75/76?

```
chrome_options = {'args': ['headless', '--window-size=1920,1080', 'no-sandbox', '--dns-prefetch-disable','--disable-dev-shm-usage']}
capabilities = {'browserName': 'chrome', 'chromeOptions':chrome_options}
cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Comment: Why is your `headless` option missing the leading `--`?

Comment: @SiKing Both are same actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `desiredCapabilities` to pass these arguments you can use `Options` instead. I have tested and it works.

*Google Chrome* - ***76.0.3809.87***

*ChromeDriver* - ***76.0.3809.68***

*Selenium* - ***3.141.0***

*Python* - ***3.7.2***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")

driver.quit()
```

Check the screenshot obtained from the headless browser below.

[image: Screenshot.png]

Comment: this answer would be good if you removed all unnecessary options and enabled headless mode with `chrome_options.headless = True`

Comment: and actually quit the driver at the end

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I just took those arguments from the question.