# ChromeOptions --headless has no effect in Selenium 3.5.3

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium 3.5.3 in my automation tool and chrome driver version updated to 76. My issue is chrome option which i set is no effect.

I tried in windows 10 machine.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1366,768");
DesiredCapability chrome = new DesiredCapability().chrome();
chrome.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
driver = new ChromeDriver(chrome);
driver.get("https://bing.com");
driver.quit();
```

In the above piece of code i am trying to run in chrome headless. But it has no effect and browser is launching and shows an execution.

chrome headless was working fine with selenium 3.5.3 and chrome driver 2.46

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [--headless flag no longer works after upgrade to chrome 76/chromedriver 76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379873/headless-flag-no-longer-works-after-upgrade-to-chrome-76-chromedriver-76)